# Set timer to submit form when all required field are validate

Tags: php, jquery, html

how to change my login button value when login is success?

i have popup error message when email and password is not registered also validate first using required in html if email format is correct and check if the email and password is empty

in this code pop-up error message is not appear when invalid credentials also button is already animate while the form have validate warning

```
$("#login").click(function(e)
{
    $("#login").html('<i class="fa fa-gear fa-spin" style="font-size:24px"></i>');
            setTimeout(function() 
            {
                $('LOGIN_FORM').submit();
            }, 5000);

});
```

in my 2nd code, the problem is no animate before logging in but all validation and pop up error message works.

```
 $("#login").click(function(e)
 {
      $('.required').each(function()
      {
          if( $(this).val() == "" )
          {
             $("#login").html('<i class="fa fa-gear fa-spin" style="font-size:24px"></i>');
            setTimeout(function() 
            {
                $('LOGIN_FORM').submit();
            }, 5000);

          }
      });
});
```

How can i change the login button if credentials meets database record ..

Answer (score 0):

In the first function, the first thing you ask jQuery to do is to find  `#login` and add the spinning gear icon.  Then after 5 seconds, to submit the form.  (Edited to add that it actually begins posting data immediately--the timeout probably never fires because there's no `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form from being submitted, assuming of course that the `click` function is the submit button being clicked.)

In the second function, you evaluate your form fields (presumably) and then if they're empty, you tell jQuery to add the Font Awesome, and start your timer. (I don't think you meant that, but that's why the spinning icon never gets added; if there's data in the `.validate` classes, the statement is unreachable.)

What exactly are you trying to do?  It seems like you actually want to do an AJAX submit of the form, and change the button if it succeeds?  Do you want the gear to be spinning *while* it's submitting?  There's nothing client-side here that I can detect--it's going to do whatever the POST action is in your login form.

Comment: do i need to use ajax or just use a timer to submit

Comment: I'm not sure what the timer would do?  You say you want to check the credentials against the database--that's AJAX if you want to stay on that page.